# How to create a Typescript type guard for my union type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, boolean, union-types, typeguards

I have the following Typescript types:

```
export type TeaserOne = { __typename: 'TeaserOne' } & TeaserOneItem;
export type TeaserTwo = { __typename: 'TeaserTwo' } & TeaserTwoItem;
export type TeaserThree = { __typename: 'TeaserThree' } & TeaserThreeItem;

export type Teaser = TeaserOne | TeaserTwo | TeaserThree;

export type FilteredTeasers = Exclude<Teaser, TeaserThree >;

export type TeaserItem = TeaserOneItem | TeaserTwoItem | TeaserThreeItem;

For example the item types looks a bit like:
// TeaserOneItem:

export interface TeaserOneItem {
  type: string;
  id: string;
  title: string;
  lead?: string;
}

// TeaserTwoItem:

export interface TeaserTwoItem {
  type: string;
  id: string;
  title: string;
  duration?: string;
  image?: Image;
}
```

In a certain React component I need to create a [Typescript type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
const filteredItems = data.items?.filter(
    (item) =>
      item?.__typename.includes('TeaserOne') || item?.__typename.includes('TeaserTwo')
  );
// -->  Maybe also I can refactor above with a type guard, but how exactly?

{filteredItems.map((node, index) => {
          if (isTeaserOne() // <-- Here I want to use a type guard) {
            const teaserOne = node as TeaserOneType;

            return (
              <TeaserOne
                key={teaserOne.id}
                title={teaserOne.title}
                lead={teaserOne.lead}
              />
            );
          }
          const teaserTwo = node as TeaserTwoType;
          return (
            <TeaserTwo
              key={teaserTwo.id}
              title={teaserTwo.title}
              image={teaserTwo.image}
            />
          );
        })}
```

How do I create a nice and clean type guard function `isTeaserOne()`? So far I have:

```
const isTeaserOne = (teaser: TeaserItem): teaser is TeaserOneItem =>
    typeof teaser === 'object' && teaser.type.includes('TeaserOne');
```

But how do I have to use this? Or do I have to refactor above type guard function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `isTeaserOne = (teaser: Teaser)` use Teaser class, so have the __typename property, you can use it directly

```
    const isTeaserOne = (teaser: Teaser): teaser is TeaserOne => teaser.__typename === 'TeaserOne';
    const isTeaserTwo = (teaser: Teaser): teaser is TeaserTwo => teaser.__typename === 'TeaserTwo';
    const isTeaserThree = (teaser: Teaser): teaser is TeaserThree => teaser.__typename === 'TeaserThree';
      
   

    filteredItems.map((node) => {
           // here typeof node is Teaser 
           if (isTeaserOne(node)) { 
                // here typeof node is TeaserOne
                <TeaserOne />
            }
            if (isTeaserTwo(node)) {
                // here typeof node is TeaserTwo
                <TeaserTwo />
                }
            if (isTeaserThree(node)) { 
               // here typeof node is TeaserThree
                <TeaserThree />
                }
            return "nothing";
        })
```

In fact, is suppose your code is incomplete, beacause in facts you do not need a typeguard here.
a simple

```
if (node.__typename === "TeaserOne") { 
        // here typeof node is TeaserOne
        <TeaserOne />
    }
```

Would give the same results.

Comment: Thanks. I have another use case. I have to extend type `Teaser` like `export type Teaser = TeaserOne | TeaserTwo | TeaserThree | SpecialTeaser;` and `export type SpecialTeaser = string;`. But now I get this error inside `isTeaserOne` type guard function: `Property '__typename' does not exist on type 'Teaser'.
  Property '__typename' does not exist on type 'string'. ` How to fix this issue?

Comment: In every type guard check if typeof teaser === 'string' return false. Then if isSpecial type guard,  if typeof teaser === 'string' return true.

Comment: Thanks. Last question. That's working for the `string`. Now I have to change `string` to `ReactElement`. Like `export type SpecialTeaser = ReactElement;`. How do I create a type guard for a `ReactElement`? I tried: `const isSpecialTeaser = (teaser: Teaser): teaser is SpecialTeaser =>
    typeof teaser === 'function';`. But then I get an error in the other type guard functions:
`Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string | JSXElementConstructor<any>'`